# Verify login credentials before notifying that email address needs to be confirmed

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, razor-pages

I'm using Asp.Net Core Razor Pages with Identity. At the moment I have RequireConfirmedAccount set to true in the ConfigureServices method of the Startup class, and I check for a confirmed email address as follows:

```
            ApplicationUser user = await userManager.FindByEmailAsync(Email);

            if (user != null)
            {
                bool emailConfirmed = await userManager.IsEmailConfirmedAsync(user);

                if (emailConfirmed != true)
                {
                    return RedirectToPage("/Account/ConfirmEmail");
                }
                else
                {
                    var result = await signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(Email, Password,
                            RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: true);

                    if (result.IsLockedOut)
                    {
                        return RedirectToPage("/Account/Lockout");
                    }

                    if (result.Succeeded)
                    {
                        // etc
```

The issue is that a malicious user could detect there's an account for this email address in the database without knowing the password. Ideally I'd like to be able to confirm the user knew the password before telling them the account email needs to be confirmed, i.e. something like:

```
                    if (result.SucceededButEmailNotConfirmed)
                    {
                        return RedirectToPage("/Account/ConfirmEmail");
```

Is there a good way to do this? The only solution I've come up with so far is to set RequireConfirmedAccount to false, then check in the code after a successful login whether the email address is confirmed, and log the user back out if not confirmed. Is there a better way to do this, or am I missing something? Thanks

Comment: > “ The issue is that a malicious user could detect there's an account for this email address in the database without knowing the password” - why is this a concern of yours? Detecting if an email address has an account is trivial: submit your site’s registration form with a sample email address. The only real security issue to worry about is if someone - who doesn’t have access to that mailbox - can somehow reset or obtain a user’s login credentials or copy an access-token/session-token - which your code already does.

Comment: Thanks - I agree it's a small risk, but I thought it was best practice for a site not to disclose whether it has an account for a given email address without knowledge of the password.  My new account registration page doesn't tell a user that an account couldn't be created because an account for that email address already exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Troy Hunt, Microsoft MVP has a great post that talks about how to make a secure password reset page (which has some similarities to your scenario):

https://www.troyhunt.com/everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know/

If you read the section titled "Username enumeration and the impact on anonymity," the recommendation would be not to display a message on your page that changes depending on whether or not you have a user account associated with that email in the database.  Rather, you will send the information to the email address on what to do next.  The next step could be they need to register (as they do not have an account), or it could be a link to confirm their email.

Also, here is a follow-up post further discussing disclosure of website data via enumeration:

https://www.troyhunt.com/website-enumeration-insanity-how-our-personal-data-is-leaked/

Comment: Thanks for these articles. The advice to display an unchanging message regardless of whether or not there's an account for the email in question seems the best way to go for now, so I'll mark this question as answered on that basis.  But a better solution would be for the sign-in method to return a result that indicates the correct password was entered but the email address has not been confirmed.  You could then safely notify your user of this. I'll look into submitting this to the Asp.Net Core team as a new feature request.